# create a CCMenuItemLabel with a custom font file

Tags: ios, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCMenuitemLabel

```
  CCMenuItemLabel *startGame = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:str target:self selector:@selector(startGamefn)];
```

and I was wondering how I would load a font file as you would do in CCLabelBMFont (example :

```
CCLabelBMFont *label = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:str fntFile:@"good_dog_plain_32.fnt"];
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CCMenuItemLabel can accept CCLabelBMFont so you can just past the `label` object in the function call to `CCMenuItemLabel`:

```
CCLabelBMFont *label = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:str fntFile:@"good_dog_plain_32.fnt"];
CCMenuItemLabel *startGame = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:label target:self selector:@selector(startGamefn)];
```