# CCMenuItemAtlasFont usage

Tags: ios, fonts, cocos2d-iphone

Can anyone please tell me the usage of CCMenuItemAtlasFont? I can't find no examples anywhere on the web and have no idea how to pass the .fnt file. the only public function that seems to make sense is

```
[[self alloc] initFromString:<#(NSString *)#> charMapFile:<#(NSString *)#> itemWidth:<#(int)#> itemHeight:<#(int)#> startCharMap:<#(char)#> target:<#(id)#> selector:<#(SEL)#>
```

where charMapFile seems to be the png. but i have no idea thow to use itemWidth or itemHeight for my fontatlas (made with bmpGlyph) has no fixed raster.

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well CCMenuItemAtlasFont uses CCLabelAtlas to generate the text textures. And (from the CCLabelAtlas.h comments:

```
// CCLabelAtlas versus CCLabel:
// - CCLabelAtlas is MUCH faster than CCLabel
// - CCLabelAtlas "characters" have a fixed height and width
// - CCLabelAtlas "characters" can be anything you want since they are taken from an image file
```

so i would guess you are cold out of luck for variable width fonts. You need width and height to specify the 'fixed' character font number of points.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628893/create-a-ccmenuitemlabel-with-a-custom-font-file)  for an example with a font file

Comment: Ok, i got it clearer now. what i need is CCLabelBMFont but for MenuItems. as far as i can see there is only the possibility to create ttf or atlas fonts right?

Comment: I have not experimented with it myself, but I would try a CCMenuItemLabel object, where the label is created with CCLabelBMFont ... according to doc can read in a .fnt file

Comment: @wolfgant : i have added a link for an example in the answer